# Is there any way to extract all the tokens from solr?

Tags: lucene, solr

How can one extract all the tokens from solr? Not from one document, but from all the documents indexed in solr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like this(This sample is approved to be working on a lucene 4.x index):

```
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);
IndexReader reader = isearcher.getIndexReader();
Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(reader);
Collection<String> cols = reader.getFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL);
for (String col : cols) {
Terms te = fields.terms(col);
if (te != null) {
    TermsEnum tex = te.getThreadTermsEnum();
    while (tex.next() != null)
        // do something 
        tex.getTerm().text();
    }
}
```

This iterates over all columns and also over every term per col. You may lookup the methods provided by TermsEnum like `getTerm()`.